# org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["weather"] is not a string

Tags: java, json

I am currently using a weather API from https://openweathermap.org/api and I'm trying to convert a JSON page into printable strings. To be more specific. Im tryying to print out the Array of "weather" as the key but its not working:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException {
        String URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=miami&appid=2550e0628a9e7428e4ef85626feb1c95";
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet getURL = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(getURL);
            HttpEntity entity = response1.getEntity();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            json.getString("weather");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    }

}
```

The JSONObject structure is this:

```
    "coord": {
        "lon": -80.19,
        "lat": 25.77
    },
    "weather": [{
        "id": 804,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "overcast clouds",
        "icon": "04n"
    }],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 301.17,
        "feels_like": 303.16,
        "temp_min": 300.93,
        "temp_max": 301.48,
        "pressure": 1018,
        "humidity": 74
    },
    "visibility": 16093,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 4.6,
        "deg": 80
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 90
    },
    "dt": 1591061650,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 4896,
        "country": "US",
        "sunrise": 1591007368,
        "sunset": 1591056495
    },
    "timezone": -14400,
    "id": 4164138,
    "name": "Miami",
    "cod": 200
}
```

The error:

```
    at org.json.JSONObject.wrongValueFormatException(JSONObject.java:2590)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:863)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Im trying to get the "weather" section of the JSON or any sub section of the JSON. Could someone help me with my code?

Comment: What are you trying to do with weather? As the message and the JSON explicitly show, it's not a string, so of course getString won't work.

Comment: I'm fully aware.... hence why I'm asking for help? I'm new to JSON but not new to JAVA and programming...

Comment: When you type it in your IDE, the autocomplete will offers several method on typing json.get, getJSONArray and getJSONObject while the others are the primitive-specific like getInt or for getting names like getNames. Next time pay more attention on the IDE and the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
json.getString(key);
```

Returns a string `if` the value of the specified `key` is a `String`.

In your case, the value of `weather` is a `JSONArray` and not a `String`.

You should do:

```
json.getJSONArray("weather");
```

---

Ideally, you should check if the key exists, or have a default value to avoid `NPE`.

```
if (json.has("weather") && json.get("weather") instanceof JSONArray) {
    json.getJSONArray("weather");
}
```

Unless you are 100% sure of the `JSON` structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getString` for string values,
if its boolean you should use `getBoolean` if decimal `getDouble` or something..